# Present a UIViewController from UIImagePickerController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I've written an app that launches the camera directly. I want to launch a view with settings as a modal view of UIImagePickerController, but directly after its presentation, it's disappearing.

What is the correct way to do this? I want the app to be full screen so I am using an overlay view on the UIImagePickerController.

Any ideas? I am targeting iOS7 or later.

I've added some source. This is called from my UIImagePickerController derived class.

```
SettingsTableViewViewController *controller = [[SettingsTableViewViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: And see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799879/present-another-modal-view-from-uiimagepickercontroller?rq=1

Comment: I solved this though by adding my navigation.view as a subview of my overlay view. Seem to work.